# The most efficient way to decipher some text

Tags: java

I am developing a small application where I am given some string *"MRUGDQ"* and a shift value 3 for example. Then I shift each letter to left by 3 and the result would be *"JORDAN"*. For instance `M` would be replaced by `J` and `R` would be replaced by `O` and so on.

So now this is the approach I was thinking of using, but I was wondering if this is efficient and can I improve my solution?

Assumptions I make:
I am assuming my string will be either capital A to Z letter or small a to z letter and therefore the ascii range is from 65 to 90 and 97 to 122 respectively.

Pesudo Code

1. get ascii value of char
   (assume char happens to be between the capital letter range)
2. add the shift value to the char ascii value
3. ```
   if new ascii value <= 90
       replace old letter by new letter
   else
       int diff = new ascii value - 90
       while (new ascii value <= 90) {
           decrement diff value by 1
           increment new ascii value by 1
       }
       add remaining diff to 65 and set that as new ascii value
   replace old letter by new letter
   ```
4. Do that for each letter in the string.

Please let me know if my approach is correct or if I can be more efficient.

Comment: Your loop is kind of strange. If the new value is larger than 90, then just do `(X % 90) + 64`.

Comment: @Tom you are correct, please post that as answer i can upvote you. Your solution is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see much to improve, except your handling of the new char is out of range.
If you like to "roll" the overlapping amount back to the beginning of your range, than just calculate: `(x % 90) + 64`(*) (with `x` being the ascii value after adding the shift value).

Example:

```
'Y' (89) + 3 = '\' 92
92 % 90 = 2
2 + 64 = 'B' (66)
```

You need to start from *64*, to avoid skipping over `'A'`, which has the value *65*.

(*) The general formula is: `(value % upper bound) + (lower bound - 1)`.
You could also use `(value % upper bound + 1) + lower bound`.